# Performing calculation server and client side

Tags: php

I have three variables. Two are server side from a database:

`$base_duration = $arr['adzone_buyandsell_duration']`

and

`$base_price = $price['price']`

both are `int`. The third will be user input: `<input type="text" name="duration" value="">` I need to preform a calculation like such: `$cal_price = $base_duration / $base_price * user_input` I then need to be able to pass `$cal_price` back to be able to charge the user the correct price. I'm fairly familiar with php, but don't know how to perform this calculation in real time not when the form is submitted.

Comment: Ajax is your friend. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: He didn't specify he was using jQuery but yes to AJAX

Comment: Or you can pass your values to the html and calculate `cal_price` on the client side. But if the values are secret or they can be changed in realtime and you want to be sure they are up to date then use Ajax as other commenters already wrote.

Comment: @Jono20201 that makes sense and is what I thought, unfortunately I've never used ajax before. how would I go about combining the variables to preform the calculation?

Comment: @chapay that sounds like what I want. the values are not secret and wont change. the only one that will change is the user input.

Comment: @Terminus I assumed that because he asked this question he was not familiar with jQuery, and IMO using jQuery is much easier than writing it in raw JS.

Comment: Then do it. Do you want me to write an answer with an example?

Comment: @Terminus yep, not familiar with jquery but willing to try

Comment: @chapay that would be great

Comment: I think AgeDeO's answer is OK except the fact there is actually [no need](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ssRUr.gif) to use JQuery in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the first two values only change when the page is loaded or resfreshed, there is no need for a AJAX call.

Add the following code to your page:

```
<script>
$('document').ready(function(){
       $('#duration').change(function(){
          var base_duration = <?= $arr['adzone_buyandsell_duration'] ?>;
          var base_price    = <?= $price['price'] ?>;
          var userInput     = $('#duration').val();
          var cal_price     = base_duration / base_price * userInput;

          $('#calPrice').html(cal_price); 
       });
});
</script>
```

It will add the calculated result to a div with the id `calPrice` and you have to give the input field the id `duration`

I created a jsFiddle for you to see the code in its full glory. I just used dummy data for your php variables.

https://jsfiddle.net/03e3t137/

Make sure you add jQuery on your page by adding the following line in your `<head>`

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Please provide an example without using JQuery as in this case it's not necessary.

Comment: @chapay - Why wouldn't you want to use jQuery. I personally prefer jQuery above javascript because the code is much cleaner with jQuery.

Comment: @AgeDeO http://youmightnotneedjquery.com However, as OP already has it on his site, the point is moot

Comment: @YobdDigital - When you are happy with my answer, I would like to ask you to accept te answer by clicking on the checkmark below the anwer score.

Comment: @AgeDeO I now have that working, but I need to update a php array with the new `cal_price` how would I pass that to php?

Comment: @YobdDigital `<form>` POST?

Comment: @AgeDeO I would convert the strings to numbers before using them in the calculations (e.g. `+$('#duration').val()`).